# Am I supposed to be paid even though my work isn't used?

Tags: payment-terms, payments, information-technology

There is a person I know that needed a logo for a game server, we talked and he found out that I have experience and have skills in Photoshop to make a decent logo, so he asked me to make a logo that he would pay for afterwards, then apparently it appears to be that he has asked a few other people to make a logo for him as well (about 3 more), so then when everyone is done he will pay to the best one. My question is: Is that what happens in freelancing business? So others don't receive anything for spending their precious time and working hard creating a logo image??

I'm just not very experience in the freelancing field, so I have no idea how it works.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some *contest* sites that operate under similar terms -- everyone sees the design description/brief, everyone works and submits designs, only the chosen design (winner) gets paid. So yes, in some cases things operate how you've described. These sites are customarily (but not exclusively) populated by hobbyists or non-freelance workers.

In terms of a freelance **business**, NO. That's **not** how freelance **business** operates. In the business of freelance design, an artist is hired, a contract is signed which details payment and work to be performed, and *then* the work performed. Customarily the artist is paid regardless of whether the final artwork is used or not. In addition, many contracts have a "kill fee" or cancelation clause that compensates the artist for their time should the client cancel the project before completion.

Most professional freelancers avoid the "contest" scheme completely. It is **never** beneficial for a professional to work on the speculation of *possible* payment/return. Professionals customarily don't work for free. See http://www.no-spec.com or merely Google for "[are design contests worth it?](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=are%20design%20contests%20worth%20it)" to understand just how **bad** the "contest" model is for artists.

Basically, this "person you know" is taking advantage of everyone and has all the upside and none of the downside. All the artists are being ripped off. Chances are even the chosen design won't be paid adequately without a contract in place **before** work begins.

Comment: You nailed it!!!

Comment: This exactly. And always always always have a contract before work starts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no as the answer above states of you were hired and did sign a contract stating you are going to recieve  payment for each logo then yes you should be paid.  Now in the case that you listed it sounds like there was no type of agreement so to answer no.  The main thing I would say in a situation like yours is to find out the fine print of the job or task and what you are going or not going to recieve.  I see this as being an artist, of any kind.  The artist is asked to make a certain painting if the painting doesn't sell then there is no payment.  I've done free lance design for tattoos and I never was paid unless the client chose my design, with that being said I knew going in that my work my not get me the money for the hours I put in.  Now I have also been asked to do other jobs involving art and I've set a dollar amount before the job.  So learn from this situation and get some kind of understanding about how the situation will unfold.  i.e. Get a contract negotiate a price before you put any time into the project.